# Java Script Event while waiting to load

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any event that fires while the page is trying to load . I dont mean onload , which fires only after the page has been loaded. I want to use it for  when the user is waiting for the new page to load

Comment: No, but just executing some JS code will probably work.

Comment: The pickle here would be the definition of 'trying'. Do you mean trying to load the DOM? or downloading the actual page that contains the JavaScript?

Comment: I meant like a gif or something while the page transition occurs.Yes while trying to load the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)** fires before the onload event.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event that you mention. For more information visit this page:

https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded

I hope it helps ;)